# Problem with reticulate type conversion from python to R (on Windows?)

Tags: python, r, pandas, reticulate

I am using the `reticulate` R package and would like to source a python function in R which returns a simple `pandas` data frame. There seems to be a problem with the conversion of the pandas data frame to an R data frame when doing so on a Windows 10 OS (in contrast to MasOS with R and python versions being the same). The following minimal example illustrates the issue.

The python function looks as shown below:

```
def func():
   import pandas as pd

   d = {'A' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.]),
     'B' : pd.Series(['x', 'y', 'z'])}
   df = pd.DataFrame(d)
   return df
```

When I run the following R code on MacOS it returns a normal R data frame:

```
> library('reticulate')
> source_python('func.py')
> df = func()
> df
  A B
1 1 x
2 2 y
3 3 z
```

However, when I run the same code on a Windows 10 OS I get the following output:

```
> df
                              A                                 B
1 <environment: 0x000000001be35ed0> <environment: 0x000000001bfb33a8>
2                              <NA>                              <NA>
3                              <NA>                              <NA>
Warning message:
In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
  corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
```

Does someone know what the problem here might be and if it is directly or indirectly related to the OS at all?

Comment: I can confirm this same problem exists on Windows 7, making it more likely it's a Windows-specific issue

Answer (score 0):

For my case I was reading the data from an S3 bucket and I had the same issue. what helped for me was adding in the Python function the following snippet:

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = np.array(df[c].values)
```

So the Python function would look like this:

```
def get_data_from_db(db_name, query):
    df = wr.athena.read_sql_query(
    sql=query,
    database=db_name,
    ctas_approach=False
    )
    for c in df.columns:
        df[c] = np.array(df[c].values) 

   return df
```

Hope this helps.